# Flask - set URL for file

Tags: python, html, web-applications, flask

I've created a simple app in `Flask`. When the user fill the form in, which is in the `index.html` it returns `results.html` template which is very similar to index but the results are returned here (results are data from database found using the form).

I would like to make "results.html" able to recieve data so I can fill in the form, see the results and again fill the form...etc.

The problem is that I don't  know how to set the "results.html" to recieve those data because when they are rendered, there is still "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" without any suffix - results.html or something hence I can't assign function which works with the input.

```
@app.route('/results.html' ....
```

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import request,render_template,Flask
from databases import db_manager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

def is_instance(a):
    return isinstance(a,basestring)

app.jinja_env.globals.update(is_instance=is_instance)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# @app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        if query.isdigit():
            _data = db_manager.manager().get_subject_by_ICO(query)
        else:
            _data = db_manager.manager().get_subject_by_name(query)


    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('results.html', data = _data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, I can go to: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" and fill in the form and see the data but I can't do it again without refreshing the page.

Do you know what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler example (without the database stuff).

**app.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        _data = 'querying "{q}"'.format(q=query)
        return render_template('results.html', data=_data)

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="query">
 <input type="submit" value="Query">
</form>

{% block results%}
{% endblock %}
```

**results.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block results%}
  {# only rendering data here #}
  {{ data }}
{% endblock %}
```

But now you have a different issue to solve - reloading the page will send a `POST` request again. You need to employ the *[Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/flask-web-development/9781491947586/ch04.html#_redirects_and_user_sessions)*.

**app.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request, session, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hard to guess string'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']
        _data = 'querying "{q}"'.format(q=query)
        session['data'] = _data

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('index.html',
                           data=session.get('data'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="query">
 <input type="submit" value="Query">
</form>

{% block results%} 
  {{ data }}
{% endblock %}
```